# Is there a better way to Count the Number of matching characters in a pair of strings in Kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin, methods, character, string-matching

```
fun compute(l: String, r: String): Int {
    var counter = 0
    for (i in l.indices) when {
        l[i]!=r[i] -> counter++
    }
    return counter
}
```

Is there an inbuilt function that can be used instead of looping over every character explicitly?

Assuming

1. strings have equal length
2. position of chars matters
3. comparison is case-sensitive

Comment: What are your criteria for "a better way"?
Does a character's position matter, or can it be anywhere in the string?
Does case matter?

Comment: Case matters, character's position also matters

Comment: better way in the sense of using built in functions in kotlin or trying to reduce the time complexity

Comment: thanks for updating the question to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do count if the order does not matter:

```
return l.count { it in r }
```

However, if you want to check that the value and the index match, you cannot escape using index:

```
l.forEachIndexed { i, it -> 
    if(i < r.length && it == r[i]) counter++ 
}
```

**UPD:** Oh I just found out that there is `commonPrefixWith`

```
return l.commonPrefixWith(r).length
```

Answer (score 3):

What about using [`zip`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html) like this:

```
fun compute(l: String, r: String): Int {
    return l.zip(r).count { it.first != it.second }
}
```

Comment: This does shorten the code, however was wondering of the existence of an inbuilt function that compares it for us. Thanks for this answer. Looking out for another.

Comment: Should this not be `==` instead for testing equality as per question?

Answer (score 0):

```
fun String.compute(r: String): Int {
  return toCharArray()
    .zip(r.toCharArray())
    .count { (l, r) -> l != r }
}
```

Assumptions:

- strings have equal length
- position of chars matters
- comparison is case-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a viable option, but just posting since I'm playing around with some Kotlin just to learn the language a little bit:

```
fun compute(l: String, r: String): Int {
    return Regex("(.)(?=.{"+(l.length-1)+"}\\1)").findAll(l+r).count()
}
```